# Friend sent me Bitcoin using Quickbt and it never ended up in my wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, difficulty, money

One of my friends sent me bitcoin so I could buy something online. They used the website quickbt to send me the money. They used the proper address for my wallet because it was copied and pasted in. That was three days ago and I still haven't received the bit coin. The wallet I'm using is bitcoin-core, and whenever I open it on my laptop there's a loading bar at the bottom of the window that says synchronizing to network (it's been doing that for three days as well). I was wondering if anybody could help me or if anyone has had this problem before?

Comment: It can take a few days for your wallet to synchronize with the network, so just be patient, and don't shut down bitcoin-core.  It will need to stay on in order to synchronize.  In the meantime, you can inspect the transaction on a block explorer like blockchain.info, just to make sure that it has gone through.  If so, your bitcoin will be waiting for you when your client is synchronized :)